# Adding RelativeLayout with LayoutInflater and set Text to TextView

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I would like to have to add a RelativeLayout XML file depending on a json array length.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        Log.i("Length", "Is " + jsonArray.length());

                        JSONObject customer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.e("Customer", "is " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                        RelativeLayout rl[] = new RelativeLayout[jsonArray.length()];
                        rl[i] = new RelativeLayout(ChatActivity.this);
                        if (sharedPrefsUser.getInt(SharedPrefsInformation.ID_FROM_LOGGED_IN_USER, -1) != sender) {
                            rl[i] = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_left, null);
                        } else {
                            rl[i] = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_right, null);
                        }
                        TextView textViewMessage = (TextView) rl[i].findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
                        textViewMessage.setText(customer.getString("message"));sharedPrefsUser.getInt(SharedPrefsInformation.ID_FROM_LOGGED_IN_USER, -1));
//                    Log.i("")

                        Log.e("Message", "is " + customer.getString("message"));
                        linearLayoutWithMessages.addView(rl[i]);
                    }
```

But now it will be add only one time...
The json arary length is four. Any suggestions? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to create the RelativeLayout array (rl) outside the for loop.

```
 RelativeLayout rl[] = new RelativeLayout[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not :-(

Comment: Did it not give the expected result or can't you create the RelativeLayout array outside the for loop? Now you create a new array every time and add one item to it.